# Generating a lettering in python?

Tags: python

How to write a function ( a generator) that takes three letters (`l1`, `l2`, `l3`) and three numbers (`n1`, `n2`, `n3`) and gives all the possible combinations in which `l1` occurs `n1` times, `l2` `n2` times and `l3` `n3` times.

For example:

```
for i in function('a', 2, 'b', 1, 'c', 0):
    print(i)
```

gives:

```
aab
baa
aba
```

Comment: That is certainly something you could do, and [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) will help, but where's your code so far?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations), all you need is a thin wrapper around it:

```
from itertools import permutations

def l_n_times(l1, n1, l2, n2, l3, n3):
    return permutations(l1*n1 + l2*n2 + l3*n3)
```

Demo:

```
>>> for item in set(l_n_times('a', 2, 'b', 1, 'c', 0)):
...     print(''.join(item))
...

baa
aba
aab
```

`permutations` already returns a generator so you don't have use `yield` yourself.

Comment: As `permutations` doesn't check whether the different characters are the same, this returns duplicates.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Issues fixed.

Comment: Well, strictly seen this is a set that you're iterating through, not a generator anymore. It will use quite a bit of memory with many letters.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Any suggestions for improvement?

Comment: @AlexThornton I'm trying to figure that out myself actually, but I've not found a good solution using itertools (yet) :)

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't seem to me that `itertools` would help a lot here, though a recursive implementation may look like this:

```
def combine(l1, n1, l2, n2, l3, n3):
    counters = {l1: n1, l2: n2, l3: n3}  # remaining characters to use
    buf = []                             # string under construction
    def recur(depth):
        if not depth:  # we've reached the bottom
            yield ''.join(buf)
            return
        # choosing next character
        for s, c in counters.iteritems():
            if not c:  # this character is exhausted 
                continue
            counters[s] -= 1
            buf.append(s)
            for val in recur(depth-1):
                # going down recursively
                yield val

            # restore the state before trying next character
            buf.pop()
            counters[s] += 1

    length = sum(counters.values())
    return recur(length)

for s in combine('a', 2, 'b', 1, 'c', 0):
    print s
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets admit you have a data structure like:

```
letters = {'a': 2, 'b': 1, 'c': 0}
```

a recursive function would be:

```
def r(letters, prefix = ''):
    for k,v in letters.items():
        if v > 0:
            d = dict(letters)
            d[k] = v - 1
            for val in r(d, prefix + k):
                yield val
    if all(v == 0 for _, v in letters.items()):
        yield prefix
```

No duplicates, and it does use a generator. Quite heavy compared to a simple itertools call.

Comment: As with Alex Thornton's original answer, this will print duplicates

Comment: yes it will. I will figure some recursive thing that does not, to give a different answer

Answer (score 0):

The docs for itertools have this to say;

> The code for combinations() can be also expressed as a subsequence of permutations() after filtering entries where the elements are not in sorted order (according to their position in the input pool):

Since we want all combinations with no duplicates, we'll just enforce strict ordering (ie only yield values that are greater than the greatest one so far);

This would seem to do just that;

```py
def dfunc(l,n):
  old=[]
  for i in it.permutations(''.join(list(a*b for a,b in sorted(it.izip(l,n))))):
    if i > old:
      old=i
      yield i

>>> dfunc(['b','c','a'],[1,0,2])
<generator object dfunc at 0x10ba055a0>

>>> list(dfunc(['b','c','a'],[1,0,2]))
[('a', 'a', 'b'), ('a', 'b', 'a'), ('b', 'a', 'a')]
```